# Angular 4 Date Pipe converting wrongly

Tags: angular, date-pipe

I have rest service which returns a collection of objects and one of the field of the item is a date string (ISO-8601 format ) and the date value as follows

> "createdDate" : "2017-02-21T12:56:50.907",

In the angular4 UI I put DatePipe to format the above date

```
{{resultItem.createdDate| date:'short'}}
```

and I am getting wrong conversion as follows

> 2/21/2017, 7:56 AM

instead of

> 2/21/2017, 0:56 AM

Comment: It's probably due to timezones, `createdDate` is being parsed as UTC rather than your local time, so it gets converted from UTC to your local time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may need to create a UTC date from your date with timezone... I assume you are in the pacific timezone as the time is 7 hours from UTC...

Try this code to get a new date object without Timezone (assuming your variable is named "date"):

```
var datewithouttimezone = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
```

Comment: Thanks Birwin.  if it is single date I can easily do like you mentioned above . My REST service returning a collection of object and this date is one of the field in that. is there any way  I can apply this logic to entire collection ?

Comment: As noted in other comments, now that angular 5+ is released, there are other options.

Answer (score 32):

I resolved the issue by adding a custom pipe.

My custom pipe is based on the solution provided by Birwin. **Thanks Birwin**.

Here is my custom pipe named UtcDate

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'utcDate'
})
export class UtcDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): any {

    if (!value) {
      return '';
    }

    const dateValue = new Date(value);

    const dateWithNoTimezone = new Date(
      dateValue.getUTCFullYear(),
      dateValue.getUTCMonth(),
      dateValue.getUTCDate(),
      dateValue.getUTCHours(),
      dateValue.getUTCMinutes(),
      dateValue.getUTCSeconds()
    );

    return dateWithNoTimezone;
  }
}
```

And I also used default date pipe to format

```
{{createdDate | utcDate | date:'short'}}
```

Comment: if you, a reader of this, use angular >= 5, you definitely should check the answer by Samuel Luis. This answer is good for Angular 4 and below

Comment: it is not working in angular 8. can you please help me?

Answer (score 27):

You can pass another param to date pipe as follows:

> {{resultItem.createdDate | date : 'short' : 'UTC'}}

This param can be a timezone like `'-0430'` or just `'GMT'`

See documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: The question is for Angular 4, which doesn't support that.

Comment: even if this is not working for angular4 still this is what I needed for angular 7 and found it here. google kinda effects upvotes but what can I do ...

Comment: Best answer here

Answer (score 0):

I used moment.js in this scenario. it worked for me. The angular version is 8

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'utcDate'
})
export class UtcDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): any {

    if (!value) {
      return '';
    }

    const dateWithNoTimezone = new Date(moment.utc(value).format());

    return dateWithNoTimezone;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<small class="text-muted ml-auto">{{n.createdAt | utcDate | date :'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a '}}</small>
```

Answer (score 0):

use these :

in your component:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

in html page

```
{{resultItem.createdDate | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm': 'UTC' }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the below code to html file,

```
{{ value | date:'short':'UTC+offset'}}
```

In component.ts file get the value of offset,

```
this.offset = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
```

It will convert UTC time to local time.

Comment: @lkatiforis sorry for inconvenience now have edited the code and tested it it was working