# Angular change date after conversion

Tags: angular, date, pipe

I have this variable

```
public to: Moment;
```

and his value is (it is a Moment type variable, not a string)

```
 2019-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z
```

in html when i use | date for change format angular change the value of date

```
{{to | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'}}
```

the result is

```
01-01-2020 01:00
```

I don't undestand how prevent this behavior.

Comment: It's likely using the date in the browser's time zone. Use the time zone argument to the pipe and use "UTC".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 Date Pipe converting wrongly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264992/angular-4-date-pipe-converting-wrongly)

Comment: @HereticMonkey with : "UTC" not work.

Comment: Please try all of the answers on the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Ok thanks pipe work!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an error with timezones, try passing timezone as a parameter to angular's date pipe.

```
{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}
```

and example would be

```
{{ to | date : "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", "en-GB", "GMT"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public to: Moment;
     to.toDate();
```

to convert it to a Date Object